# How to disable write barrier on docker thinpooldev?

Tags: docker, device-mapper, diskcache

My server has very low disk performance if write barrier is enabled. As it has a disk controller with battery for the cache it is safe to add the "nobarrier" option to /etc/fstab. This makes a huge difference in performance. I want to the same for docker, but I'm using device mapper and not a regular partition. How can I disable write barriers in docker when using docker with device mapper?

```
$ cat /etc/sysconfig/docker-storage
DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS=--storage-driver devicemapper --storage-opt dm.fs=xfs --storage-opt dm.thinpooldev=/dev/mapper/fedora-docker--pool
```

Answer (score 0):

You must try dm.mountopt=. Just add in your config:

```
--storage-opt dm.mountopt=nobarrier
```